# How to Bind google places in a textbox using c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

> How to Bind google places in a text box with Google API using c#?

I have tried using javascript to bind google place. Here is the code:

```
function initialize() {
    var autocomplete = newgoogle.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtAutocomplete'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var location = "<b>Address</b>: " + place.formatted_address + "<br/>";
        location += "<b>Latitude</b>: " + place.geometry.location.A + "<br/>";
        location += "<b>Longitude</b>: " + place.geometry.location.F;
        document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = location
    });
}

</script>
<span>Location:</span>
<input type="text" id="txtAutocomplete" style="width: 300px" placeholder="Enter your address" /><br/><br />
<label id="lblResult" />
</body>
</html>
```

This is how this code gets called:

```
<script src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/…
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But is doesn't return the place

Comment: Please add part of code where you are calling this fuction

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jsv=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Comment: You can [edit] your question.